# How to Style each sentence differently to one placeholder

Tags: html, css

i was styling the place holder and i use ..

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: #535252!important;
font-size: 18px;
position: relative;
bottom: 03px;
font-weight: 600;
}
```

But that is one style , how can i apply multiple styles in one place Holder as you can see in the picture

[image]

Comment: You should use some alternative for placeholder-proof-solution something like this http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text/comment-page-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's more complex (not only input element). Something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label class="prefix">
        Prefix:
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" />
</div>
```

and a css:

```
div.wrapper {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 300px;
padding: 4px;
}

div.wrapper input {
border: 0 none;
background-color: transparent;
outline: none;
}
```

See [example](http://output.jsbin.com/weqoja)